# Scipy KDTree get rectangular subset of grid defined by two points

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I am using the following example from :

```
from scipy import spatial
x, y = np.mgrid[0:5, 2:8]
tree = spatial.KDTree(list(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())))
pts = np.array([[0, 0], [2.1, 2.9]])
idx = tree.query(pts)[1]
data = tree.data[??????????]
```

If I input two arbitrary points (see variable `pts`), I am looking to return all pairs of coordinates that lie within the rectangle defined by the two points (KDTree finds the closest neighbour). So in this case:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

How can I achieve that from the tree data?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found a solution:

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
x, y = np.mgrid[0:5, 0:5]
tree = spatial.KDTree(list(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())))
pts = np.array([[0, 0], [2.1, 2.2]])
idx = tree.query(pts)[1]
data = tree.data[[idx[0], idx[1]]]
rectangle = tree.data[np.where((tree.data[:,0]>=min(data[:,0])) & (tree.data[:,0]<=max(data[:,0])) & (tree.data[:,1]>=min(data[:,1])) & (tree.data[:,1]<=max(data[:,1])))]
```

However, I would love to see a solution using the query option!